# Pycharm ImportError Could not find cudart64_80.dll

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, tensorflow

I downloaded and installed CUDA 8.0 and put CuDNN 6.0 where the folder of CUDA 8.0 is but when I try to compile and run it on pycharm, it gives me the error

```
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_80.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 8.0 from this URL
```

I am using pycharm for the compiler and it works when I installed the normal library of tensorflow but not tensorflow-gpu

Could anyone help figure out this issue for me? I had check that there is cudart64_80.dll in the folder

Comment: The `_80.dll` represents the CUDA version number. It is looking for CUDA version 8.0. The latest version of CUDA is 9.1. Perhaps the environment variables are pointed to the wrong version of CUDA? Check `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA` to see which version(s) of CUDA you have and the environment variable `CUDA_PATH` to see which one it is set to.